# Property ribbon doesn't exist on office

Tags: controls, office-js, ribbon

While working on enabling/desabling a control in an Excel web complement the editor throw the following error :""property 'ribbon' doesn't exist on type 'type of office'" from an 'Office.ribbon instruction'.

My Excel Version is : 2104 (Build 13929 20296)
Here is a snapshot of the code [code with office.ribbon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rvps7.png). This code comes from  https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/office/dev/add-ins/design/disable-add-in-commands. Note than isSetSupported('RibbonApi', '1.1') ==true

Screen shot :
[Xml of my addin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMNpd.png)

Comment: Can we see your app manifest file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you specified the latest Office JavaScript API library in the add-in manifest. If you use runtime checks, you need to reference the most current version of the Office JavaScript API library from the content delivery network (CDN). To do this, add the following script tag to your HTML. Using `/1/` in the CDN URL ensures that you reference the most recent version of `Office.js`.

```
<script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: I did check. This is ok

Comment: It makes sense to chare the manifest file.

Comment: Nope. Try running any sample web add-in with ribbon controls. Do you still get such errors?

Comment: Yep. I did this morning two try with new projects.  One with VStudio 19  and js. Here office.ribbon seems ok but the xml line <Enabled> false </Enabled> generates an error  when runing the complement. The other with  Yeoman and ts. Here I get the same error for office.ribbon

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to use message boxes. Off course it's quite Ugly, but I need to publish my app shortly. I hope that by this time I will find a way to actually enable/desable commands on this addin.